# Angular 2 Send Objects between not related components

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

I am trying to send data to another component from a Component that isn't a child nor a parent.

I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAAwjTeg2Go1Rs0AY5uA?p=preview) to show what i am asking.

when the following code is fired I would like something to listen for it.

```
 fillSelectT(item){
  //populate Select to
}
```

the following code should listen for the data.

```
  listener(item){
    selectedItems.push(item);
  }
```

In C# it would be simmular to an `EventAggregator` what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service): you should share a service between the two components, emit events from the service when selecting an item, and listen to the events emitted from the other component.

```
@Injectable()
class SelectionService {
  selections = new Subject<any>
  select(item) {
    this.selections.next(item);
  }
}
```

Your plunkr, modified: http://plnkr.co/edit/qJ8bh7wN9qQvKTLJOb0T?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I did I full working exemple based on yours.

1) Both components are child of `AppComponent`, then create variable and events to fire and store those:

```
selectedItems: any[] = [];

onSelectItem(item) {
   this.selectedItems.push(item);
}

<select-from (onSelectItem)="onSelectItem($event)"></select-from>
<select-to [selectedItems]="selectedItems"></select-to>
```

2) Modify the `select-from` component to fire an event:

```
@Output() onSelectItem = new EventEmitter<any>();

 fillSelectT(item){
      this.onSelectItem.emit(item);
 }
```

3) Modify the `select-to` component to receive a list from it's caller component:

```
@Input() selectedItems:any = [];
```

Here the modifications:[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdei8o?p=preview)